# Add reviewers to azure devops pull request in api call

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm successfully creating PR requests in Azure DevOps using [API-call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#identityrefwithvote).
However, I would like to add the reviewer's name to my PR. As per the sample in the link, I have to add the `reviewer id` in the body.
So, my question is how to dynamically find the reviewer's id prior to submitting the PR from my project? I was following [Pull Request Reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20reviewers?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and nothing seems coming up to provide me the id based on name.
As per branch policy, I have to add 2 reviewers' name.

```
{
  "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/npaulk/my_work",
  "targetRefName": "refs/heads/new_feature",
  "title": "A new feature",
  "description": "Adding a new feature",
  "reviewers": [
    {
      "id": "d6245f20-2af8-44f4-9451-8107cb2767db"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Krzysztof Madej suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64655255/3025856), you can use the [Subject Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/subject-query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) endpoint to search and get the [`GraphSubject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/subject-query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#graphsubject) response.

However, the `Id` values in the `GraphSubject` response does not work for the [`IdentityRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/create-pull-request-reviewers?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#identityref) `Id` used as parameter for the [Pull Request Reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/create-pull-request-reviewers?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) endpoint (used to add Reviewers to an existing pull request).

To get the correct `IdentityRef` `Id`, you need to do a `GET` on the URL from the `storageKey.href` value in the `GraphSubject` Response. E.g.:

```
"storageKey": {
                "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/StorageKeys/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
            },
```

The response should look something like this:

```
"value": "73b67dcb-6969-62f2-8075-99834ae11234",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/StorageKeys/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
    },
    "descriptor": {
        "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/Descriptors/73b67dcb-6969-62f2-8075-99834ae11234"
    }
}
```

The GUID for `value` is what you use for `IdentityRef.Id`. The payload to `POST` to the Pull Request Reviewers endpoint would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "73b67dcb-6969-62f2-8075-99834ae11234"
  }
]
```

Comment: Disappointing it seems the API has changed because this doesn't hold true anymore. The storage key no longer has a value in the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Subject Query Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/subject%20query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/subjectquery?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Body should look like this:

```json
{
    "query": "Term to search (e.g. Krzysztof)",
    "subjectKind": [ "User" ]
}
```

and then you will get response like this:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "value": [
        {
            "subjectKind": "user",
            "metaType": "member",
            "domain": "Windows Live ID",
            "principalName": "mail@mail.com,
            "mailAddress": "mail@mail.com",
            "origin": "msa",
            "originId": "0006BFFDBC3FE9A1",
            "displayName": "Krzysztof Madej",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/Users/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
                },
                "memberships": {
                    "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/Memberships/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
                },
                "membershipState": {
                    "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/MembershipStates/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
                },
                "storageKey": {
                    "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/StorageKeys/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
                },
                "avatar": {
                    "href": "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
                }
            },
            "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/_apis/Graph/Users/msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3",
            "descriptor": "msa.MDQ5MGM0N2ItODNiNC03MmEzLTk2MzgtZTJhMmNjOTY3NWQ3"
        },
```

as next ise `originId` in `reviewers` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Identities - Read Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) API to get user id. For example:

```
Get https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=cece dong&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Comment: I tried to use `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<organization>/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=random user name&queryMembership=None&api-version=6.0` --> This throws me error `"Message":"Either descriptors or identityIds or searchFactor/factorValue must be specified"`

Comment: Did you run the api from a script? Could you share more about how you use this api? I've tested this api in Postman, it works as expected.

Comment: I will update a bit later haven't got time further to look into. Will look into this again very soon. thanks.

Comment: @ Cece Dong - MSFT has not got a chance to take a look at this because stuck with some another AzDo issue, maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824802/trigger-another-build-exist-in-project-in-azure-devops/64852348#64852348

Comment: I've noticed the issue is solved in that link. If there is any update for this case, kindly let us know.

Comment: It's working now, if I give the filterValue=`firstname lastname` --> space in between it doesn't work also `firstname, lastname` also doesn't work so i search using email address it works fine. like this `newurl="https://vssps.dev.azure.com/organisation/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=a.b@random.io&queryMembership=None&api-version=6.1-preview.1"
                ret=$(curl --silent -X GET -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" -H "Content-Type:application/json" ${newurl} --write-out "%{http_code}" --output /tmp/response1.json)`